# Filter on values in a multi-dict with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, filter

I am using Python to filter on the dictionary below:

```
dct={'variable1':np.array([12,3,45,78]), 'variable2':np.array([34,45,89,90]), 'variable3':np.array([23,77,89,65]),'"state':np.array(["closed","open","closed","open"]), "values_state":np.array([740,760,780,720])}
```

Basically, I only want to keep the values (of all keys) for which the keys `state="open"` and `"values_state">=750`. If one sees that as a table, it should then return "the 2nd row":

```
dct={'variable1':np.array([3]), 'variable2':np.array([45]), 'variable3':np.array([77]),'"state':np.array(["open"]), "values_state":np.array([760])}
```

Would you have any ideas on how to do so without converting the `dict` into an `array` and converting it back into a `dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using pandas module

1. Create a `Dataframe` from `dict` using `pandas.DataFrame()`
2. filter rows which satisfy your conditions

   - `df['state']=='open'` would give you a bool series indicating rows where `state` is *open*,
   - df['state']=='open' works similarly similarly.
   - bit wise **and** them to get resulting bool series, this represents rows that satisfy both your conditions
   - index `Dataframe` using this bool series ie `df[<bool series>]`
3. convert the resulting `Dataframe` back to `dict` using `.to_dict(orient='list')`, `orient='list'` is used to get `dict` like `{column -> [values]}` [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dct={'variable1':np.array([12,3,45,78]), 'variable2':np.array([34,45,89,90]), 'variable3':np.array([23,77,89,65]),'state':np.array(["closed","open","closed","open"]), "values_state":np.array([740,760,780,720])}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

dct = df[(df['state']=='open') & (df['values_state'] >= 750)].to_dict(orient='list')

print(dct)
# if you want the lists as numpy arrays

dct = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in dct.items()}

print(dct)
```

**Output-1:**

```
{'variable1': [3], 'variable2': [45], 'variable3': [77], 'state': ['open'], 'values_state': [760]}
```

**Output-2:**

```
{'variable1': array([3]), 'variable2': array([45]), 'variable3': array([77]), 'state': array(['open'], dtype='<U4'), 'values_state': array([760])}
```